# Symfony 4 - authentification 1form 2tables

Tags: forms, authentication, symfony4

I would like to know if from the same login form we could connect from two tables: User and Player

Here is my attempt.

security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
        App\Entity\Player:
            algorithm: auto

```
providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [mon_provider_player, mon_provider_user]
    mon_provider_player :
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Player
            property: email      
    mon_provider_user :
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email          

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    player:
        anonymous: lazy
        provider: mon_provider_player
        form_login:
            login_path: login 
            check_path: login
             success_handler: redirect.after.login
        logout: 
            path: logout
            target: login 
    main:
        anonymous: lazy
        provider: mon_provider_user
        form_login:
            login_path: login 
            check_path: login

            success_handler: redirect.after.login
        logout: 
            path: logout
            target: login
        remember_me:
            secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
            lifetime: 604800  # 1 an par défaut
            path:     /
            domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER

access_control:
    - { path: ^/pol, roles: ["ROLE_POLISTE"] }
    - { path: ^/user, roles: ["ROLE_USER"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Here to help if needed

Everything happens in the file: loginFormAuthenticator.php which extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator in symfony.

There are 5 methods, one of which allows the $user in several tables.

```
    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $userFound = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);

        if ($userFound !== NULL) {
            return $userFound;    
        } else {
            return $this->playerRepository->findOneBy(['emailJoueur' =>  
             $credentials['email']]);
        }
    }
```